# react-router: change route from component or store

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactjs-flux

I'm using bundle of React, Flux and react-router (v4).
My aim is to implement server side validation and depending on validation result redirect to another route or stay on current and show validation messages.

My idea follows this scenario:

1) component collects data and calls action

2) store gets response whether data is valid, keeps result and emits changes

3) component detects changes and collects state. If validation is successful then redirects to new route

The part of functionality in component looks like (written in TS):

```
public componentWillUpdate(): void {
    if (this.state.status === ValidationStatus.OK) {
        this.context.router.history.push(/* another route */);
    }
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <input type='text' ref='Field1' />
                <input type='text' ref='Field2' />
            </div>
            <span onClick={ (e) => this.tryToValidate(e) }>Go</span>
        </div>
    );
}

public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
    MyStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
}

private _onChange() {
    this.setState({
        status: MyStore.getStatus()
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work properly - redirect is triggered only on second click.

How shall I change my code to make it work? Probably calling redirect from store or something else?...

P.S. router's history is included in component this way:

```
public static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.shape({
        history: PropTypes.shape({
            createHref: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            push: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            replace: PropTypes.func.isRequired
        }).isRequired
    }).isRequired
}
```

**Update:**

Find one solution that works, but looks ugly:

- pass from component callback to store as payload (callback raises `context.router.history.push(/* another route */);`)
- execute this callback in store if server validation is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out solution. It's just necessary to include to history to store like (it's just draft, not working code):

```
import * as history from 'history'

class MyDataStore {

    private dataService = new ValidationService();

    constructor() {
        super();
        AppDispatcher.getInstance().register((payload) => {
            let action = payload.action;
            switch (action.actionType) {
                case AppActions.VALIDATE:
                    this.dataService.validate(action.data).then((validationOk) => {
                        if (validationOk) {
                            history.createHashHistory().push(/* another route */);
                        } else {
                            this.emitChange(); // stay on current route
                        }
                    });

                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }

            this.emitChange();
        });
    }

}
```

The only disadvantage is that it's working just with HashRouter not with BrowserRouter. I don't know reasons why, trying to find out...